# apache 2.4 and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, apache2.4

after upgrading to apache2.4.12, when I click on a link that is an outlook email attachment (.msg), I get scambled characters instead of having the messages downloaded.  This only happens in IE(10, 11), Chrome and Firefox work just fine.
I tried to add "application/vnd.ms-outlook msg" to the config files, which didn't make any difference.
I went back to apache2.2, everything works just fine including IE.
I made sure it's not the file system that matters in this case.  IE and apache 2.4 are the differences.

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

it seems in apache 2.4, I need to explicitly specify

AddType application/vnd.ms-outlook .msg

while apache 2.2, that wasn't necessary.